# SQL cross table based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want make cross table in MySQL based on two columns in table. One is evidence number of bus: called "boczny" (without repetitions in the column) and number of lane: "linia". I try convert the "linia" column to row, and count how often evidence bus was seen on a given lane.

Acutualy I have this, but still mising pivot table (cross table).

Please help.

```
SELECT boczny, MIN(linia)
FROM  vehicles
GROUP BY boczny
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: could you give a sample of the data and the desired output?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Snap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to do this uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT v.boczny,
       SUM(v.linia = 1) as linia_1,
       SUM(v.linia = 2) as linia_2
FROM vehicles v
GROUP BY v.boczny;
```

Alternatively, you could put each `linia` on a separate row:

```
SELECT v.boczny, v.linia, COUNT(*)
FROM vehicles v 
GROUP BY v.boczny, v.linia;
```

Comment: If I have 100 lines then I have to type each one in SUM?

Comment: @Wanarka . . .  You can construct the clauses using a spreadsheet or query.  Or, you can put a separate count on each *row* in the result set rather than in a column.